# Install Ioncube Loader on an Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, whmcs, softaculous, ispconfig-3

I want to install Ioncube Loader on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, in order to install Softaculous and WHMCS, by following this tutorial:

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-ioncube-loader/

The problem is that I'm not sure about the correct php.ini file I should modify. I tried modifying all of them from the following paths:

```
/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/cgi/php.ini
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

but it only worked with the one from this path: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini, and I don't know why.

However, I want to be sure about what the correct setup is in order to avoid any future mis-configurations.

Comment: Each one is specific to how the script is run, so if you use fpm you need to change the fpm one. If your scripting/automating it (bash), 18.04 is the latest LTS and php upstream is php 7.2 so your going to encounter changes in the future.. scripting it or practising will make you more comfortable with installing extensions and mitigate *future* misconfigurations, there is no silver bullet fix..

Comment: Also if you download the dist from the official site, open the tarball, there is a readme, a pfd which shows you how to install it.. also a php script (wizard) which I suppose guides you through installing it.